# From .jar to importable package... How?

Tags: java, netbeans, import, executable-jar

I have a .jar file that is sitting in one of my folders after I downloaded it from a tutorial website. This .jar file includes all of the necessary packages needed to be imported to a specific program I wish to run (i.e., it is a client that allows me to communicate with the server I need to use for this project), but I don't know how to transfer the .jar file into a package so that I can directly import the necessary packages for this project. Do I have to transfer the file into a Maven repository (which I have no idea how to do) or do I have to use some hidden technique to transfer the file over so I can import directly from the file? Or is it a really quick fix that just takes two minutes?

F.Y.I.:

- I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1 for the said-Java project.
- I am not heavily experienced with all the ins-and-outs of the IDE, so I need simple instructions.
- I barely understand what a Maven repository is or does. I only have heard of a Maven repo through "Help" websites.
- I have tried multiple "Help/fix-it" sites but only got vague answers, like "run 'make'".

  - **My response**: How does one 'make'? **Their response**: ...

Comment: The phrase you probably want to search for is "add jar to build path". Netbeans should have a graphical way of doing that.

Comment: If you already have it downloaded you just have to add the jar to your java classpath. Most IDE's (netbeans, eclipse, intellij, etc) allow you to add local jar's to the projects class path. If you're compiling it in command line then just use the `-cp` option for `java` / `javac` commands